# Mage_Customer_Model_Customer extend not working

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, extend

I am trying to extend the authentication function, I have extended classes many times with out issue but this ha stumped me

**app/etc/modules/Dev_Customer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dev_Customer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Dev_Customer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Dev/Customer/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dev_Customer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Dev_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <customer>
              <rewrite>
                  <customer>Dev_Customer_Model_Customer</customer>
              </rewrite>
          </customer>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Dev/Customer/Model/Customer.php**

```
<?php
class Dev_Customer_Model_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer{

    /**
     * Authenticate customer
     *
     * @param  string $login
     * @param  string $password
     * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
     * @return true
     *
     */

    public function authenticate($login, $password)
    {
        $this->loadByEmail($login);
        if (!$this->getId()) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please re-register as your email address cannot be found, sorry.'),
                self::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD
            );

        }

        if ($this->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired()) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed.'),
                self::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED
            );
        }

        if (!$this->validatePassword($password)) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid login or password.'),
                self::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD
            );
        }
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_customer_authenticated', array(
           'model'    => $this,
           'password' => $password,
        ));

        return true;
    }
}
```

It is just not being called, I have flushed the cache, checked, double checked etc.. nothing I do seems to help.

I am running Magento 1.9.1.0 CE

I am sure it is something silly but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

I have migrated from another platform and I need to let customers who did not get migrated they need to re-register, the aim is to do this automatically once I get past this hurdle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have do small mistake:**

at  a*pp/etc/modules/Dev_Customer.xml* , **codepool** should be `codePool`.**p** should Uppercase Letter `(P)`.

This is magento pattern

Comment: OMG! How did I miss that! I have written huge amounts of modules. Thank you